# How to Update Gradle Spring Boot Dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, rest, github, gradle, arduino

I am struggling to get the following project to run after many hours of updating many aspects of the build.gradle file to include gradle version, spring-boot RELEASE, and altering many of the dependencies, as well as ensuring that the gradle-wrapper.properties were updates as well.

I am on a Windows 10 x64 and have the latest JDK installed. I have managed to get VSC to move the error past line 16: and line 43: (this wrapper syntax is deprecated)of build.graddle, but then the methods are overrun with errors.

I would at least be happy if at minimum I knew that this project is too old to be wroth the time reviving, and better to start new, but I am not sure that I have the skills to execute a fresh build on my timeline.

If someone experienced could give me a vector, I would greatly appreciate it.

https://github.com/morzel85/blog-post-spring-arduino.git

Comment: Gradle 1.12 isn't really going to work. You need at least something in the Gradle 5 or 6 range.

Comment: I re-built the project and at least have Spring Boot running now with no debug issues in VSC; however, I am still seeing the following:                                               'Failed to start bean '_webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat serve_r' after context initialization. I am wondering if it is due to the @PreDestroy disconnect method serial !=null on line 44 of ArduinoConnection.java?

Comment: I figured it out. Nothing more than needing to change server.address = 192.168.0.17 to 192.168.0.21 and now it runs perfectly after the Spring Boot refresh.

I sent a pull request prior to the change, but everything else was the same and I learned a ton about Spring Boot, Tomcat, and Gradle in the process.